# C++ Error project.cpp:11:20: error: no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'std::__cxx11::list<int>' and 'int')

Tags: c++

Ok, so I'm relatively new to c++ and I'm trying to self-teach with youtube tutorials and websites. What I'm trying to do is to make a list, then add things inside the list. That worked fine until I tried to get something inside the list. I get the error project.cpp:11:20: error: no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'std::__cxx11::list' and 'int'). Idk why this happens.

Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    list <int> numbers;
    for (int i = 0;i < 10; i++){
        numbers.push_back(i);
}
cout << numbers[0];

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::list` is not random access, so it has no `std::list::operator[]` - if you want random access use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: `list` does not provide the operator `[]`. THe compiler tells you exactly that. Maybe you're looking for `vector`?

Comment: Use std::list front() to b get the first element of the list (which you need to check is not empty first, otherwise it will probably crash)

Comment: Since you are self teach c++, you'd better read some books, and look up the http://en.cppreference.com/w/ when you need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In c++, the STL `list` doesn't support `operator[]`. The reason for this is that it is implemented as a liked list. This means that each item only knows where the elements before and after it are. The `list` would look something like [this](https://www.sitesbay.com/cpp-datastructure/images/linked-list-in-cpp.png).

Instead of accessing a given part of the list through the brace notation, you want to use a loop to iterate through the list until you reach where you want.

```
int count = 0;
for(auto iterator = list.begin(); iterator != list.end(); iterator++)
{
    if(count == inputNum)
    {
        // Do whatever you need, or save the iterator to perform operations on
        break;
    }
}
```

You can also use the `STL` method `advance`. It takes in an iterator and the distance you want to move it:

```
std::list<int>::iterator iterator = list.begin();
std::advance(iterator, numPositions);
```